# What is the grammatical facts of "as" in the sentence?

Tags: grammar, relative-pronouns

I read this sentence in the Cambridge touchstone student's book. 
*

> The scenery is amazing, as is the peace and quiet.

*
I want to know what the meaning of "as" is in the sentence?

In my point of view, "as" here is a pronoun and can be used interchangeably with "which". It leads a non-restrictive attributive clause.

Is that right?

After looking up the dictionary，I have another opinion about “as”， I think “as” in this sentence is conjunction，which means how something happens or is done, or to indicate that something happens or is done in the same way as something else. And "as is the peace and quiet" is an inversion sentence.

Comment: The preposition "as" has a comparative meaning here. It heads the PP "as is the peace and quiet" that has the comparative clause "is the peace and quiet" and has as complement of "as". The PP functions as an adjunct of comparison in that it makes a comparison between the peace and quite and the scenery, both of which are amazing. Yes, the comparative clause has subject-auxiliary inversion.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase 'as is' is used because of the following:

This sounds awkward because of the two 'and's in this sentence:

> The scenery, **and** the peace **and** quiet is amazing.

As a native speaker, I would also use 'as is' to add additional information to my initial statement.

It's a nicer way of saying this:

> The scenery is amazing, and the peace and quiet is amazing.

Once again because of the repeating statements.

Comment: I now think "as" is a conjunction and "as is the peace and quiet" is inversion sentence. Is that right?